# Returning JSON instead of html error page when REST API method not exist in JAVA

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, jersey

I am adding REST API to my web application. All REST addresses are in ../rest/... What I want to do is return JSON : {error: not found} message when client try to invoke address which is not exist. For example :
../rest/users - OK
../rest/xxxx - return {error: not found} where xxxx can be any string.
Now when calling to ../rest/xxxx glassfish handle request and returns html error page.

Is there a way to disable glassfish from returning html error page for specific addresses (../rest/..) and to map all not existing urls to method which will return error formatted in JSON.

Comment: It should just return 404. Rest api's should rely on error codes to show the problem

Answer (score 1):

In applications that I have developed I have two hierarchy of pages; ones that return HTML (and HTML error messages) and ones that return JSON (and JSON error messages).

This technique may be of help here.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not write a filter that intercepts all requests and return a json response for urls that do not follow the /rest/ url pattern ?

For example using the Jersey rest service, you would have a mapping like this

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Rest Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>    
    </servlet-mapping>
```

You could add a Filter with a mapping

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>RestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And then in the filter's doFilter method

```
public void doFilter(...){
   if(match using a regex pattern){
        chain.doFilter(request, response);  //matches, send it to servlet            
   }else{
        response.setContentType("application/json"); //no match, send an erro
        response.println("{error:'value'}");
    }
}
```

You may have to adjust the filter pattern to allow images and such stuff, but this gives you an idea to get started with.